# I am having trouble writing Join statements in Big Query

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have no idea what my syntax error is. I keep getting it at the end even if I try to put the whole table name instead of the alias.

```
SELECT 
    'my-project-spawsome-sales.SpawsomeSales.Orders' AS Orders,
    'my-project-spawsome-sales.SpawsomeSales.Customers' AS Customers,
    Orders.OrderID,
    Orders.OrderDate,
    Orders.ProductID,
    Orders.CustomerID,
    Customers.CustomerName
FROM 
    `my-project-spawsome-sales.SpawsomeSales.Orders`
LEFT JOIN 
    `my-project-spawsome-sales.SpawsomeSales.Customers`
        ON (Orders.CustomerId = Customers.CustomerID);
```

I get an error on the last line saying

> "Orders" is incorrect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

putting table name in select is wrong, you should be selecting column names, if you want all the columns, you can use select * . I think that's what you are trying to do , give tables an alias and select the columns you want:

```
 SELECT 
    Orders.OrderID,
    Orders.OrderDate,
    Orders.ProductID,
    Orders.CustomerID,
    Customers.CustomerName
FROM `my-project-spawsome-sales.SpawsomeSales.Orders` as Orders
LEFT JOIN `my-project-spawsome-sales.SpawsomeSales.Customers` as Customers
  ON (Orders.CustomerId = Customers.CustomerID);
```